How to politely tell to a colleague to be more specific?
I got an email from a colleague from another branch asking for help.
The email goes more or less like this:

Hi everybody,
I’m gonna loop the team who has a bit more experience with this XYZ thing.
[insert my name here], can you help please help John Doe?
Thanks

What follows is an email thread that already has 10+ replies consisting of technical questions and discussions.
After taking a very quick look at the email thread, I think I might be able to help with the issue at hand, because I am indeed familiar with the system they are dealing with, and I am willing to do so, but only if the problem is more easily summarized and explained, as right now it is not clear to me.
How can I politely tell this person that I have no time, no intention and no interest in reading through the whole email thread, and that if he wants my help, he should ask it in a way that doesn't make me waste hours just to figure out what the issue is?

I always found, the classic, "can you be more specific" is helpful in getting additional specific information.  It works better than, the good old fashion, "what in the heck are you talking about" and the unprofessional and rude response "WTF?"

While it's good to have details captured in emails, this sounds like a problem crying out for an in-person (or virtual) discussion.

Rethought after I commented, totally your call to ask for a summary or not. I think you may be overthinking this though, IMO its as easy as replying back to just your colleague:

This thread is a little overwhelming to come into the middle of. Can you please provide me with a few paragraphs summing up the main issue and where we currently stand? Thanks.


@mrodo This is answer is so on the point and simple. There is never harm in asking for clarification and a summary.

This is right on point, especially when OP was not on the email thread originally

Why bother a human with writing a summary? Ask your generative AI of choice to do it. While you're there, ask it to suggest how you might respond too!

Instead of continuing on the existing email thread, try to connect 1:1 (over phone, IM or a seperate email) and ask them for a discussion to understand the context in a better way. That way you can have a focused discussion and can quickly understand and reach to the root of the issue, to provide a solution or assist with some guidelines.

This is the better option. No point gumming up the main email trail with catch up questions. Do that out of band, then come in and say: "With respect to this... blah".

@GregoryCurrie : I disagree. Phone calls give room for interpretation and no one in the mail conversation will have any idea what went on. If you leave it to the other party to make a list like user InBedded16 suggested, you can hold them accountable for not specifying enough. Also, no one can say with a straight face afterwards that something was on a list but never done. I always prefer writing over calling, especially in cases like this where work is expected.

@JustLudo I said the main email trail. If you're paranoid about politics and need a paper trail, you can always do it in a seperate email.

and no one in the mail conversation will have any idea what went on but they need not bother with activity details, do they? Once the problem is understood and a solution can be framed, we can have the original thread updated, right?
